# How best to count views per page, per user, on a high traffic website?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a website that will have articles, and it will support the ability for people to sign up as an affiliate (and get a subdomain) and get paid per 'View' that they send to the website (they typically post their links on facebook pages which drive the traffic to my site)

So a typical URL could be `http://johnsmith.mydomain.com/post/an-interesting-article`, where 'johnsmith' is an affiliates username. Now the problem I am seeking suggestions for is how to go about tracking the views on these articles per each ‘Username’. I have designed the below schema but I know it needs improvements, the site will initially get 30,000 to – 50,000 page views, so writing to a database every single time someone loads a page is completely unnecessary.

[image]The View part is definitely not set in stone, it is just an idea.

Basically I need to store which username sent how many views to a given page. One other thing also, I need to store the IP address because I won't be paying for clicks that come from certain countries.

Using: MySQL, web server will either be Apache or xgnix

How best to go about this?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use MySQL?  You might be better off using a `NoSQL` datastore like CouchDB for this.  You can still keep the rest of your application in MySQL, just this particular part may be better suited to be stored somewhere else.

Comment: No requirements at all, its just me creating this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at high-performance NoSQL database solutions for this problem.
[Redis](http://redis.io/), for example, is a in-memory key-value store with very high performance. You can adjust persisting the records to the disk according to you needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google analytic s codes. 
Assign a new UA- Code / Custom variables from Google for each new sub-domain . Then you can track according to each page type . Read more about Google analytics .

[Read here about Google Analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/)